python jupyter simplify equality with 2 expression doesn't work and cannot put equation in two lines
From this code :
Declare symbols :
from sympy import *
r,l,c=symbols('r,l,c', real=True)

The first equation :
b=sqrt(2)*sqrt((-r**2/l + 2/c)/l)/2
display(b.simplify())
display(b.subs({r:1,l:2,c:3}))


Second equation :
d=sqrt(-c**2*r**2+2*c*l)/(sqrt(2)*c*l)
display(d.simplify())
display(d.subs({r:1,l:2,c:3}))


There are equals but not here :
display(simplify(b-d) == 0)


False

h=simplify(b-d)
display(simplify(h))


It cannot be simplified


I have 2 questions :

How cant I get equation in 2 lines (pretty print ) like the 'd' equation  ?
How to retrieve equality ?

Thanks
